# Sum of functions rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I know that when dealing with linear maps $f,g:V\rightarrow W$, then $(f+g)(υ)=f(υ)+g(υ)$

However if we have two functions $f,g:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$, which are not necessarily linear maps, then is $(f+g)(x)$ just a different notation for $f(x)+g(x)$, or does the rule $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ only apply for some special cases of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: $f+g$ is defined by $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$, for arbitrary maps $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Adren Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ for any maps, by definition.

For linear maps, $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x,y$ in the domain, which isn't true for functions in general.

Comment: Maps, say, not necessarily functions? Same goes for $fg$ and $\frac{f}{g}?$

Comment: @Michael I'm using "maps" here as synonymous with functions. Yes, $fg$ and $\frac{f}{g}$ are also defined as $(fg)(x) = f(x)g(x)$ and $\frac{f}{g}(x) = f(x)/g(x)$ $\bigl($provided $g(x) \ne 0\bigr)$.

Comment: What if $f,g$ aren't functions?

Comment: @Michael Then you'll need to explain a bit more. What sort of $f$ and $g$ do you mean?

Comment: Say, $f=x^2+y^2-1,g(x)=x$